# Div not displaying/showing - unable to assign box-shadow

Tags: html, css, displaytag

A div area isn't behaving normally.

[Here's the link](http://intelsystems.in/testing/)

(all the styles are in theme.css files)

In the `HTML` file there is a `<div>` which starts on line 89 and ends on line 94, has two classes assigned to it, I cannot apply `box-shadow` property to it, I have set the display to block, set the background color to black to check if it displaying but for some wired reason it just does not display.

I could apply margin to the div (theme.css line 280).

Any help on how to display it normally (with the box-shadow) would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you name the divs you're having issues with please.

Comment: You gotta add an exclamation to that DOCTYPE declaration. Should be: `<!DOCTYPE html>` That's messing with your markup exponentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add the box-shadow property because the div.dropdown-toggle (the element in question) has not a height and a width.

Try putting (like a test) these CSS rules:

```
div.dropdown-toggle {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;
}
```

You'll see the div with the shadow.

Cheers,
Leo

Comment: Thanks a lot, instead of giving width and height to div I've put a &nbsp; in the div and it worked!.